# Bootstrap row margin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I decrease the screen size, one of the button is pushed to next line. I want **at least two of them to be together**. I tried using the **"col"**, but on large screen sizes it increases the left-right margin between the buttons

```
<!--BANNER-->
<div class="container-fluid" id="banner">

    <!--MAIN BUTTONS SECTION-->
    <div class="row button-container">
        <button class="icon icon-me">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/PNG/256 px/cabin.png">
                <div class="button-overlay">
                    <h1>Myself</h1>
                </div>
        </button>
        <button class="icon icon-work">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/PNG/256 px/Wallet.png">
                <div class="button-overlay">
                    <h1>Work</h1>
                </div>
        </button>
        <button class="icon icon-goal">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/PNG/256 px/Tent.png">
                <div class="button-overlay">
                    <h1>Goal</h1>
                </div>
        </button>
        <button class="icon icon-message">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/PNG/256 px/Pencil.png">
                <div class="button-overlay">
                    <h1>Message</h1>
                </div>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/manankukreti14/hfg5j7vL/

Answer (score 0):

Even after your updates, your code is not complete, but try to use media queries, not only columns and the default style from Bootstrap.

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
          button.icon{
             min-width:50%;
             max-width:700px;
             margin:2px 0;
           } 
}
```

Comment: On large screens they're all in a line. When I decrease the width of the window it still pushes one of them to the next line.

Comment: I understood. Did you try this code? I don't have your CSS to test this, but I'm sure it will work.

Comment: Yep, I tried it. https://jsfiddle.net/manankukreti14/hfg5j7vL/ The problem is kinda like this.

Comment: Do you want them all to stay inline while decreasing the size of the window?

Comment: @K.Daniek I want them to be split into pairs of two.